# How to import csv file for "field collection" using feed-importers

Tags: feeds, entities

In Drupal7, In node processor settings -> we can't map field collection values. However they are multiple values, Is there any way of possibilites to import data through CSV file. I tried using [field collection feeds](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_feeds) module, In Processor Settings -> I selected "Field collection processor", then alert error is dispalying as shown "Missing Feeds plugin FeedsFieldCollectionProcessor". Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same issue. Follow along with what I did:

1. Do NOT install the field collection feeds module.
2. Go here: https://drupal.org/node/1063434 and apply the patch in comment #16. (See https://drupal.org/patch/apply for details. Or you can just apply it manually, by copy & pasting the patch directly into /drupal/sites/all/modules/field_collection/field_collection.module).

   EDIT: You may find more luck with one of the other listed patches on that page. #16 worked for me, so that is the one I suggested.
3. If the field collection fields have more than one instance, use the drupal module 'feeds tamper' to 'explode' the field collection mapping.
4. Clear your site's cache
5. Set new mappings to your field collection values (they should show up now as mapping targets).
6. Import your nodes, field collections and all!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1826290) and appears to be related to caching. The suggested fix is to clear your caches at /admin/config/development/performance.